# Authentication is required to access this resource error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a registration and login with Spring Boot Security and so far all implementation works fine when I test it with Postman. Right now I want to create also a HTML side of that so user can actually sign up and log in.

There is a problem. I'm getting `Full authentication is required to access this resource`

In the stack trace there is also a line which points on `AcessTokenFilter` and that is this:

```
  @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Optional<String> accessToken = parseAccessToken(request);
        if(accessToken.isPresent() && jwtHelper.validateAccessToken(accessToken.get())) {
            String userId = jwtHelper.getUserIdFromAccessToken(accessToken.get());
            User user = userService.findById(userId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
            upat.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upat);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("cannot set authentication", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
}
```

I'm getting that error when I try to access to: `/api/auth/form`

And there is a methods:

```
@PostMapping("signup")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@Valid @RequestBody SignupDTO dto, @ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
    User user1 = new User(dto.getUsername(), dto.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword()));
    model.addAttribute("user", user1);
    userRepository.save(user1);

    RefreshToken refreshToken = new RefreshToken();
    refreshToken.setOwner(user);
    refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshToken);

    String accessToken = jwtHelper.generateAccessToken(user);
    String refreshTokenString = jwtHelper.generateRefreshToken(user, refreshToken);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new TokenDTO(user.getId(), accessToken, refreshTokenString));
}
```

---

```
   @GetMapping("/form")
   public String showForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "signup";
}
```

---

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(accessTokenEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.addFilterBefore(accessTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

And now I saw that on chrome im getting this:

```
    There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to go to /api/auth/form and you get the error?

I only see this rest mapping here:

```
@GetMapping("/form")
```

is the controller annotated with:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
```

?

Another thing: Try to work in reverse to see which part is preventing this from working: Remove spring security and see if you see the website first. Then turn security on again and try to see which lines are exactly preventing you from accessing the resource

Comment: Yeah, controller is annotated with `"/api/auth"`. When I disable security error disaperad but I got another one and that is `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
`

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but the error is quiet telling: you are sending a POST request, but your method is annoted with @GetMapping.